# IOS app update not showing in Automatic Updates list on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-update

we published App on app store,and it is available to download

after some time we released update for that app,

we know that app has an update available to download

but on App store in upcoming automatic updates list, app store is showing all other apps other than our app.

Is there anything we missed here?

Do we need to change some setting on App store connect?

I am attaching Screen shots of what I am saying

[this is Image of upcoming automatic update list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj3sh.png)

[this is image of our app on app store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzJKh.png)

I am not used to Apple/IOS stuff, but tried to find solutions on google but had no luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upcoming updates shows the apps that have opted-in for a '[phased rollout](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d65fcee1)'. If you have opted to roll-out your update to all users at once, you will not see your app under the automatic update list.